# How to handle "On-Topic" but not "in-form" questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46875/power-or-energy-signal-of-xt-t-cdot-ut) popped up at least twice in my review list and I struggled to provide a response I would feel comfortable with and this was not the only review that puzzled me lately.

The question is not "closable" or "flagable". It is possibly only ["downvotable"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) but this will not stop it from appearing as an unanswered question (of which there are more than one thousand as it seems).

Is there already a guideline about handling this type of questions? Would it be useful to be flagging them for mods to put them "on hold" until the OP improves them? Can a question be put "on-hold" for a reason beyond the ones provided by the "close" functionality? Would it be useful to have at least 2 mods review such a decision in case it could be perceived as preferential and unfair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that this sort of question needs to :

- have the <kbd>homework</kbd> or <kbd>self-study</kbd> tags associated with it.
- be closed until the OP updates it with their attempt at answering.

As you say, I think this is on-topic, but as-is this is just cheating on homework.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, adding the tags would also help.